# read_csv shifting columns and skipping wrong rows

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm using Pandas to `read_csv` to import a CSV file into a Jupyter notebook.

You can find the [CSV file at this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Eobd9FBEp-aUshpuq4aEYKrfHR79fjL1). It has two empty rows before the header row. 
When I use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/2008-03-21_downloaded.csv', skiprows= 2)
```

The resulting df has all the column headers shifted over.

If I add `index_col=False`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/2008-03-21_downloaded.csv', skiprows=[1,2], index_col=False)
```

The result uses a row of data as the header instead of the actual header names.

I can't seem to skip the first two rows and use the actual headers as headers [Account, Account Name, Amount, etc...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fix your `csv` file:

- This is the header row: `ï»¿ACCOUNT,ACCOUNT NAME,AMOUNT,AUTH CODE,AVS,BRAND,CARD ENDING,CVD,FIRST NAME,LAST NAME,MERCHANT TRANS. ID,OPTION CODE,DATE,TXN ID,CONF. NO.,ERROR CODE,AUTH TYPE,TYPE,TXT_CITY%2CTXT_COUNTRY%2CTXT_EMAIL%2CTXT_PHONE%2CTXT_STATE%2CTXT_ADDR1%2CTXT_ADDR2%2CZIP%2CCONSUMER_IP,,,,,,,`

  - The header is a little messed up.  The following code will replace `%2CTXT_` and `%2C` with `,`
- This is only necessary if you have more than one file needing fixes
- You can add additional fixes as needed.
- [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is part of the standard library

  - [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)
  - If `p = WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/Articles.csv')`
  - `p.parents[0] = WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow')`
  - `p.stem = Articles`
  - `p.suffix = .csv`

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('some_path')
files = p.rglob('*.csv')  # files in top dir and all subdirs


for file in files:
    file_updated = file.parents[0] / f'{file.stem}_updated{file.suffix}'
    with file.open('r') as f:
        with file_updated.open('w') as f2:
            for cnt, line in enumerate(f):
                if 'ACCOUNT NAME' in line.split(','):
                    print(cnt, line)
                    line = line.replace('%2CTXT_', ',')
                    line = line.replace('%2C', ',')
                    print(cnt, line)

                f2.write(line)
```

- When I downloaded and tested your file, the script was not reading additional rows before the header, which I think has to do with `ï»¿` before account, in the header.
- Instead of overwriting the old file, we will create a new file, with `_updated` appended to the `stem`.

### Read the `_updated` files into a single dataframe:

```py
p = Path('some_path')
files = p.rglob('*_updated.csv')

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in files])
```

Comment: what if you have to cycle through a folder with thousands of csv files with the same error. Each CVS holds the data for one day and there are hundreds of these files. Any way to cycle through the entire folder and update?

Comment: @SMJune  Yes.  Give me a sec.  Are all the names similar to what is shown? Are you one windows?

Comment: yes, all the file have the same structure...i was able to use this code: all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv") when i was trying to combine them all, but the formatting error addressed it above was throwing it off

Answer (score 1):

Your first version of code is OK. Two initial rows are empty and should
be skipped.

But note that one of column names in your input file (see *DATA* view -
for some time your post contained it) contains *%2C*,
which is a hex code for a **comma**.

So apparently your heading row is corrupted and this is why in your
*DATA* view there is a bunch of column titles as *Unnamed*.

One option is to make order with the title row in this detail (replace
each "%2C" with a comma) and then repeat reading.

Another option is to:

- pass *skiprows=3* parameter (skip also the header row),
- pass *names* parameter with proper column names for **all** columns.

Your second version of code is wrong, because row numeration starts from
**zero**.
Don't be misleaded by row numbers in Excel, which start from **one**.